# Importing my own packages using cx_Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I am using PyDev over Ecplise as IDE and cx_Freeze to build a windows exe starting from Python source code. Until I haven't to import my own packages everything work well but I did not find any doc or help about how to include my own packages.
In this case my project src files are in: C:\Dati\workspaces\PythonEclipse\JanasMagicKey\srcappwin
and my package is PyLibUty in: C:\Dati\workspaces\PythonEclipse\APyLibUty\PyLibUty
I tryed to edit my setup.py in several ways but it did not work (when I run python setup.py build it does not find the PyLibUty package. I am using Python 3.
This is my setup.py:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable  
buildOptions = dict( include_files = ['locales', 
                                          'key.ico', 
                                          'win.ico', 
                                          'config-mk.ini'], 
                         packages = ["cryptography", 'C:\Dati\workspaces\PythonEclipse\APyLibUty\PyLibUty'])
    setup(
        name = "Janas Magic Key",
        version = "1.0",
        description = "Janas Magic Key GUI",
        options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
        executables = [Executable("appwin.py",
                        targetName="janasmagickey.exe",
                        base='Win32GUI',
                        icon='key.ico',
                        shortcutName='Janas Magic Key')
                    ],
        # build_exe_options = {"packages": ["cryptography"] }
        )
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is PyLibUty a properly packaged Python package that you've `pip install -e`'d into your app's virtualenv, or are you doing some `sys.path` magic to make it importable?

Comment: Yes, it was. I found that to install a personal package using Pydev if it is on the same workspace the procedure is a little bit different and the error was that I specified the package pat in setup.py

Answer (score 0):

I found that to install a personal package using Pydev if it is on the same workspace the procedure is a little bit different and the error was that I specified the package path in setup.py